# Laravel form array validation doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble with Laravel 5.1 to validate an array.

**HTML CODE:**

```
{!! Form::label('information[1][color]', 'Color') !!}
{!! Form::select('information[1][color]', [null => 'Choose your color'] + $product->availableColors()->toArray() , null, ['id' => 'select-color0', 'data-id' => $product->id, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
```

**To test if the data is being passed on correctly:**

```
dd($request->all):

"information" => array:1 [▼
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "color" => "2"
    ]
  ]
```

**Validation code:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'information.*.color' => 'required'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            dd('Validation fails');
            return Redirect::to('index')->withErrors($validator);
        } else {
            ..........
```

I keep ending up at the page from the `dd('Validation fails')`. Can someone explain to me what I'm missing here and why the validation isn't working? I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/form-array-validation-in-laravel-5-2/

I have also tried:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'information' => 'required',
    'information.*.color' => 'required'
]);
```

but the validation still fails

Also tried changing the form name:

```
{!! Form::select('information[][color]', [null => 'Choose your color'] + $product->availableColors()->toArray() , null, ['id' => 'select-color0', 'data-id' => $product->id, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
```

But still no luck yet

Comment: could you please add output also?

Comment: instead of Input you should try $request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
$rules = [
        'id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'information' => 'required|array'
    ];

    foreach ($request->information as $key => $variant) {
        foreach($variant as $color){
            $rules['information.'.$key.'.color'] = 'required';
        }
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

Comment: I still think the 'information' => 'required|array' is conflicting with the elegant way, and that may not be needed... but anyways, good that you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 1 from the select name

```
{!! Form::select('information[][color]', array_merge([null => 'Choose your color'],$product->availableColors()->toArray()) , null, ['id' => 'select-color0', 'data-id' => $product->id, 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
```

or change your roules to

```
$rules = [
            'information.1.color' => 'required'
        ];
```

Comment: This is also not the problem because as you can see from the `dd($request->all())` the values are passed on correctly. Somehow the validation isn't working on the array.

Comment: now that update, which is a different point, actually is closer to what the issue is

Comment: @lagbox maybe you can help answering the question instead of just saying what is wrong!

Comment: @madalinivascu thank you for the updated suggestion. I think this is indeed closer to solving the problem. The form is dynamic. So a user can add another color input form. I'm currently working on just getting the validation for a single color to work.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine are you submitting the form via ajax or via a input form?do you have any other inputs on the form?

Comment: @madalinivascu I'm submitting the form with a post method to a Laravel CRUD store function. There are other inputs in the form like ID and Name of the product.

Comment: @madalinivascu if i change my validator to just: `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'id' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'information' => 'required|array'
        ]);` the validator is passed! Problem is really with the `information.*.color`

Comment: @madalinivascu with form name: information[1][color] and validation key 'information.1.color' the validation is passed! But unfortunately there can be multiple inputs :-( ....